# How do I standardize my data so that the Mean is 0?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to standardize a dataset in Python as part of Principle Component Analysis. I've managed to do the following so far:

```
cancer_data = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data', header=None)
cancer_data.columns = ['Sample code', 'Clump Thickness', 'Uniformity of Cell Size', 'Uniformity of Cell Shape',
                'Marginal Adhesion', 'Single Epithelial Cell Size', 'Bare Nuclei', 'Bland Chromatin',
                'Normal Nucleoli', 'Mitoses','Class']
cancer_data = cancer_data.replace('?', np.NaN)
cancer_data = cancer_data.fillna(cancer_data.median())
classDF = cancer_data['Class']
cancer_data = cancer_data.drop(['Class' ,'Sample code'], axis = 1)

# Standardization of data 
standardized = StandardScaler().fit_transform(cancer_data)
x = pd.DataFrame(standardized, columns = cancer_data.columns)
```

However when I check the Mean values, I get the following output:

```
array([-5.08256606e-17, -9.14861892e-17, -3.04953964e-17,  5.08256606e-17,
        5.08256606e-17, -8.13210570e-17,  3.04953964e-17, -1.32146718e-16,
       -8.13210570e-17])
```

I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong for these values to be wrong so any help is much appreicated (I'm new to data mining).

Comment: Those values are effectively zero. It's just that floating point arithmetic has some issues. `-5.082e-17` means `0.000...0005082` (sixteen zeros). See https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/scientific-notation.html

Comment: Just to make sure: remember that the median and the mean are two different things.

Comment: double has 53 bits mantissa., which is about 3.x * 17

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula of the standarization:
column = column to standardized

```
df_std[column] = (df_std[column] - df_std[column].mean()) / 
df_std[column].std()
```

or:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
# create a scaler object
std_scaler = StandardScaler()
std_scaler
# fit and transform the data
df_std = pd.DataFrame(std_scaler.fit_transform(df_cars), columns=column)
```

Read for more information :
https://towardsdatascience.com/data-normalization-with-pandas-and-scikit-learn-7c1cc6ed6475